# Search for First & Last Name in table from URL Parameter

Tags: php, mysql, sql, string-concatenation, mysql-real-escape-string

I am trying to pass a parameter in my url like so: http://example.com?rep_name=JoeSmith

The database table has this structure:

```
+----+-------+-------+-------------+
| id | fname | lname |    email    |
+----+-------+-------+-------------+
|  1 | Joe   | Smith | joe@joe.com |
+----+-------+-------+-------------+
```

How can I query the table and search for users that match first & last name? Right now I am only able to query using either fname or lname. The variable $rep_name holds the parameter value, but I am not sure how I can use first & last name in the parameter and in the query since they are on separate columns.

SQL:

```
$sql = "SELECT id
        FROM contacts
        WHERE fname='" . mysql_real_escape_string($rep_name) . "'
       ";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the rep name is always the first and last name appended to each other, just use [`CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) to append them and then compare them to your value.

```
$sql = "SELECT id
    FROM contacts
    WHERE CONCAT(fname,lname)='" . mysql_real_escape_string($rep_name) . "'
";
```

I just hope all of your reps have unique first name last name combinations if this is going to be used to authenticate reps in any way.

Comment: There can be a funny case when we have fname="Khuanantonio" lname="Sanpedro" and fname="Khuan" lname="Aantoniosanpedro" :)

Comment: what do u wana mean @HamletHakobyan ?

Comment: Awesome, this works perfectly! Is there a way to account for the user putting a space between the first and last name in the parameter? EXA: "&rep_name=Joe Smith" and "&rep_name=JoeSmith" should both work.

Comment: Before you pass `$rep_name` to your query strip out the space with `str_replace()`. That's the best you can do but could cause issues if someone's first or last name has a space in it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `CONCAT` a mysql function

```
 "SELECT id FROM contacts WHERE CONCAT(fname," ",lastname)='" . mysql_real_escape_string($rep_name) . "' ";
```

`CONCAT()` JOINs all stuffs in between any number of `,` commas;

Comment: They don't have a space in the repname provided via the query string

Comment: Yes i can understand that i wanna explain him what really is `CONCAT()` called ! @JohnConde